# Generate C# parser and AST with vscode-antlr4 plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, antlr4

I am using ANTLR4 to define a short grammar and generate the C# parser and lexer for the same. I am able to define and generate the c# parsers using he cmd line

```
java -jar ${ToolsPath}\antlr-4.8-complete.jar ${Project}\Test.g4 -o ${Project}\Generated -Dlanguage=CSharp -listener -visitor
```

I recently came across this nice plugin for VSCode - https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4 which I am trying to use to automatically generate the parsers and also view the parser tree. I am however unable to see the settings file to change the generation parameters to change the output directory, language target etc. Can someone help me understand where I should be adding this settings json snippet so that this takes effect?

```
    "antlr4.generation": {
        "mode": "external",
        "outputDir": "antlr4-runtime",
        "language": "CSharp",
        "listeners": true,
        "visitors": true
    }
```

Comment: The settings for it should be under the extension settings. Though you can also manually add it to your .vscode folder

Comment: @UnholySheep excuse me if this is quite basic. I tried adding it under C:/User/{user}/.vscode/.vscode/settings.json, C:/User/{user}/.vscode/.vscode/mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4-2.2.4/settings.json. But it does not take effect. I dont see it taking effect

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using the built-in settings editor of VSCode? That would not require you to guess where you need to put a file

Comment: Thank you, @UnholySheep. I was able to resolve all the issues. Never really used the built-in-settings editor of VSCode prior to this.